# can't install tensorflow even after installation with conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

Hello Stackoverflow people. Merry Christmas!

I'm having trouble with installing tensorflow.
I'm using window 10 and I installed tensorflow with this code.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

After finishing all installation, I checked if it's installed successfully at the anaconda prompt

```
(tensorflow) > python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant("Hello, tensorflow")
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

It printed out "Hello, tensorflow" very well. But after that when I tried to import tensorflow or keras on my jupytor notebook or spyder, it threw error.

```
No module named 'tensorflow'
```

The version of python is 3.7 so I tried to downgrade it.

```
conda install python=3.6
```

But still, it doesn't work. What should I do? 
I just guess downgrading didn't work well, cause I still can see 'Spyder(Python=3.7)' at the right top of the spyder window.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just use another version of Python so you can use this command to get the path of tensorflow, for some platform the default `pip` is for Python2, so maybe you will get:

```
C:\Users\Nick>pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Also from the doc [Work with multiple versions of Python installed in parallel](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) .

You can try this:

On Linux, Mac OS X, and other POSIX systems, use the versioned Python commands in combination with the -m switch to run the appropriate copy of pip:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Appropriately versioned pip commands may also be available.

On Windows, use the py Python launcher in combination with the -m switch:

```
py -2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
py -2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
py -3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

If you have a broken `pip` on Anaconda, you can follow these steps:

1. Find pip folder under "../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/", delete it manually.
2. In Anacoda prompt do : `conda uninstall pip`
3. Install pip using your familiar way. E.g: `conda install -c anaconda pip`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Nick. Thank you so much for the reply. I tried `pip show six` like you said, but the result is quite....not good.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.util.queue'`  What does this mean?...

Comment: @Jean It seems that you have a broken `pip`, see [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4330)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I tihnk I fixed pip. so I tried `pip show six` again and got the same result with yours. So found out python launcher, which was named as python.exe. 
But when I command `python2 -m pip install SomePackage` with three other lines, It threw `Invalid syntax`. Hmm...

Comment: On windows, you need use `py -3.6 -m pip install SomePackage`

Comment: I'm sorry but ..this is what I got. 
`'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: @Jean Maybe you need to take some time to read the [Anaconda doc](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/).

Comment: I took some time but failed to find out the clue from the document.I might don't have python 3.6 in my base env. And strangely when I comman `py -V`  I got `'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
But when I command `python -V`, I got `Python 3.7.0`. 
And I can't see python 3.6.exe file even when I search it manually. Would there be any clue?